# SSL Problem Downloading Resource in Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, ssl, maven, confluence

I am trying to create a Confluence plugin. I have been following theses [instructions](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DEVNET/Developing+your+Plugin+using+the+Atlassian+Plugin+SDK).

However when I run the atlas-create-confluence-plugin command maven throws SSL errors trying to get resource from https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/.

[alt text http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/6281/mavenssl.jpg](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/6281/mavenssl.jpg)

Do I need to change a setting in my configuration?

System setup: Windows  Vista, with Apache Maven 2.1.0 (r755702; 2009-03-18 19:10:27+0000)

Comment: could you give some information about your OS, Maven Version ?

Comment: thanks I have have added this to the main question.

Comment: Your jdk version would be useful here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing a repository over SSL is not really a Maven issue (which uses HttpClient under the hood and at the end classes from the `java.net` package), this is a pure Java issue: the certificate of the remote repository has to be trusted i.e. the CA root certificate for this certificate has to be in the `cacerts` file bundled in the JRE or you need to establish a chain of trust manually.

In the particular case of https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/, the certificate has been issued by DigiCert CA.

The odd part is that recent JDKs (Java 5u15 or later or Java 6u5 or later, see Bug ID:[6647251](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6647251)) have a CA root certificate for DigiCert. So, with a recent JDK, things should just work (unless you have a proxy doing some black magic like in [this issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-65)).

If you are using an older JDK and can't upgrade, export the certificate from your browser, use `keytool` to add it to a trust store and setup Java to use this trust store (using the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` system properties). See the [Maven mini guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html) and/or this [blog post](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/leeirvine/archive/2009/10/30/maven-and-ssl-cetificates.aspx) for more details on how to do this.

But the easiest way would be to use a recent JDK.

Answer (score 0):

OK this  looks like I got the question wrong.

For some reason maven was not downloading the maven-confluence-plugin-3.0.5.jar file. I had to manually download this file from the URL and add it in the correct location .m2 directory.

After that the whole process worked fine.

Comment: But maven should be able to download that file via SSL. Manually installing it into your local repository does always work, but to avoid future problems you may want to check your sll configuration.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, [Pascal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2258672/1831052) is the way to go. However, if you're building Maven itself, it doesn't work (as of Maven 3.2.3, at least), because `ant` fails to pass the necessary `javax.net` properties when it calls the `MavenCli` class to let Maven build the remainder of Maven.

The solution to this problem is to modify the `build.xml` file in the root of the maven source directory, and add these lines to the `maven-compile` target:

```xml
<arg value="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/trustStore" />
<arg value="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=TrustStorePassword" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in windows doing the following helped with command line execution

SET MAVEN_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201
jre\lib\security\cacerts"

the error I got was as follows
Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

(one could also adjust mvn.cmd...)
hope this hepls